# Unity VR Character Falling Through Ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm creating my first VR game in Unity. I followed a tutorial by Valem and got a simple XR Origin controller working. It was working fine until today, when I opened up my project and found that when I pressed play, the VR character would fall through the ground, and the hands glitch up and down very fast. I'm not sure what's happening, and I can't find help online. Please help.

[In the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ4Qh.png)
[When the game plays and the character falls through the ground. The hands are still above the ground but they are spazzing and glitching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmHag.png)

I tried resetting the Transform component of the XR Origin, but that doesn't do anything. I made sure the XR Origin and all its child objects were above ground. I really don't know what else to do. Everything was working fine until one day it just broke. Maybe it has to do with the Unity XR Interaction Toolkit? Idk.